# Is there a way to solve memory error while still using recursive method?

Tags: python

Fairly new to Python. I am trying to run a combination function and filter out the outcomes I want from all the possible combinations. But when I run n=50, Python returns MemoryError. Is there a way to resolve this while still using the recursive method? (my assignment requires us to use the recursive method)

```
from itertools import combinations:

def staircase(n):
    list1 = []
    for i in range(1, n):
        list1.append(i)
    possible_comb = []
    for j in range(2, len(list1) + 1):
        for x in combinations(list1, j):
            possible_comb.append(x)
    final = []
    for z in possible_comb:
        if sum(z) == n:
            final.append(z)
    steps = len(final)
    return steps

print(staircase(50))
```

Comment: This is currently **not** recursive

Comment: Check for the  `sum` directly in first loops, don't same ALL to filter out to keep some after

Answer (score 0):

A memory efficient code wouldn't store the combinations, neither the `possible_comb` not the `final` ones, only the quantity directly

```
from itertools import combinations

def staircase(n):
    list1 = list(range(1, n))
    steps = 0
    for j in range(2, len(list1) + 1):
        for x in combinations(list1, j):
            if sum(x) == n:
                steps += 1
    return steps
```

---

#### Time complexity

But now the amount of combinations is huge, here's some times for me

```
i=24 >> 0:00:04.260734 --
i=25 >> 0:00:08.423537 --
i=26 >> 0:00:19.787822 --

Perspective
34  >> 1:08:16     , 1 hour
50  >> 74565:24:16 , 3000 days
```

---

#### Size complexity

And some amount of combinations tested, depending on `n`

```
i=0 > 0
i=5 > 11
i=10 > 502
i=15 > 16,369
i=20 > 524,268
i=25 > 16,777,191
i=30 > 536,870,882
i=35 > 17,179,869,149
i=40 > 549,755,813,848
i=45 > 17,592,186,044,371
i=50 > 562,949,953,421,262
```

Code for it

```
from math import factorial

def staircase_combinations_amount(n):
    list1 = list(range(1, n))
    total_combi = 0
    for j in range(2, len(list1) + 1):
        total_combi += factorial(len(list1)) / (factorial(j) * factorial(len(list1) - j))
    return int(total_combi)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll try to figure it out from here :D

Comment: @Ejin Just added some values so you understand the amount of combinations it tests